# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAuthenticated') at Navbar.jsx

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, mern

Actually in my navbar I want to show login and logout at a time. And when it shows logout and If user Click on that then It should work accordingly . But is is not working properly. Rather it is showing error. `isAuthenticated` is available in reducer.js
[image: Error]

Navbar.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../../redux/actions";
import { links } from "../../data";
import "./Navbar.css";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setShowMenu(!showMenu);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/");
  };

  let filteredLinks = links;

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    filteredLinks = links.filter((link) => link.name !== "Login");
  } else {
    filteredLinks = links.filter((link) => link.name !== "Logout");
  }

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <div className={`${showMenu ? "nav_menu show-menu" : "nav_menu"}`}>
        <ul className="nav_list">
          {filteredLinks.map(({ id, name, icon, path }) => (
            <li className="nav_item" key={id}>
              {name === "Logout" ? (
                <a className="nav_link" onClick={handleLogout}>
                  {icon}
                  <h3 className="nav_name">{name}</h3>
                </a>
              ) : (
                <NavLink
                  to={path}
                  className={({ isActive }) =>
                    isActive ? "nav_link active-nav" : "nav_link"
                  }
                  onClick={toggleMenu}
                >
                  {icon}
                  <h3 className="nav_name">{name}</h3>
                </NavLink>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div
        className={`${showMenu ? "nav_toggle animate-toggle" : "nav_toggle"}`}
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

data.jsx:

```
import {
  FaHome,
  FaUser,
  FaFolderOpen,
  FaEnvelopeOpen,
  FaBriefcase,
  FaGraduationCap,
  FaCode,
  FaLock,
  FaGithub,
} from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiFileText, FiUser, FiLogIn, FiLogOut, FiExternalLink } from "react-icons/fi";

export const links = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Home",
    icon: <FaHome className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/",
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: "About",
    icon: <FaUser className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/about",
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Projects",
    icon: <FaFolderOpen className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/portfolio",
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Contact",
    icon: <FaEnvelopeOpen className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/contact",
  },
  // {
  //   id: 5,
  //   name: "SignUp",
  //   icon: <FiLogIn className="nav_icon" />,
  //   path: "/signup",
  // },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Login",
    icon: <FaLock className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/login",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "logout",
    icon: <FiLogOut className="nav_icon" />,
    path: "/",
  },
];
```

Login.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./Login.css";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", {
        email,
        password,
      });

      // Assuming the response contains a token
      const token = response.data.token;

      // Save the token to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);

      // Handle successful login here (e.g., redirect to admin dashboard)
      toast.success("Login successful", {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 1000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "light",
        onClose: () => {
          navigate("/admindashboard"); // Navigate after the toast message is closed
          setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          }, 1000); // Delay the reload by 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
        },
      });
      // Set isLoggedIn state to true
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle login error here (e.g., display error message)
      toast.error("Login failed");
      console.log("Error:", error.response.data.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="login section">
      <h2 className="section_title">
        Login For <span>Admin</span>
      </h2>
      <form className="login_form" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <div className="login_form_input-group">
          <div className="form_input-div">
            <label className="login_form-title">Email:</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Your Email"
              className="form_control"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleEmailChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form_input-div">
            <label className="login_form-title">Password:</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Your Password"
              className="form_control"
              value={password}
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button className="button login_button" type="submit">
          <span className="button_name">Login</span>
        </button>
      </form>
      <ToastContainer />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

actions.js:

```
// authActions.js

import axios from "axios";
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_FAIL = "REGISTER_FAIL";
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAIL = "LOGIN_FAIL";
export const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";

export const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/register", { name, email, password });
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: response.data.token });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};

// Login action creator
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/login", { email, password });
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.data.token });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};

// Logout action creator
export const logout = () => ({ type: LOGOUT });
```

reducers.js:

```
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT,
} from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  error: null,
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

rootreducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

main.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store.js";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

I want a solution which can help me to overcome the problem. It will be very helpful if anyone can help me to get out of this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `rootReducer` is actually your `authReducer`, so `state.auth` is undefined.

You need to get `isAuthenticated` from just state.

It should be something like this in your `NavBar.jsx`

`state.auth.isAuthenticated` ==> `state.isAuthenticated`

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `rootReducer` ***is*** the `authReducer`, e.g. `import rootReducer from './reducers';`, so there is no `state.auth` to select from.

reducers.js:

```js
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  error: null,
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  ...
};

export default authReducer; // <-- default export
```

store.js

```js
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; // <-- default import

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer, // <-- authReducer => state
  middleware: [thunk],
});
```

## Solution

`store.js` should import the default exported reducer function from `"./rootreducer"`.

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./rootreducer";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer, // <-- { auth: authReducer }
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

The `Navbar` component should then be able to correctly select `isAuthenticated` directly from `state.auth`.

```js
const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```

Comment: I forgot to add the rootreduer.jf file in the post:
`
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
`

Comment: @MahadiHasan Hmm, then `state.auth` should certainly be defined if that's the case. Are you sure you are importing the correct "rootReducer" function into `store.js`? Please update your post to include all the correct, relevant code, with correctly labeled file names so export/imports are clear. Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

Comment: If I use this:
const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.isAuthenticated);
then error goes but as in my Navbar.jsx I want to show logout and login link conditionally It didn't work now. And If I click on the logout it should remove the token from the localstorage and redirect to "/". It is redirecting to home now but it is not removing the token from localstorage.
What to do to solve this issue

Comment: @MahadiHasan If you want to remove the token value from localStorage then the logout handler can call `window.localStorage.removeItem("token");`.

Comment: If I provide github repository. Is it good for you?
As I am not that much familiar with codesandbox.

Comment: @MahadiHasan Did the hint above to remove the token in the logout handler work for you? A running, minimal, live example would be better, but a link to the repo is ok, with regards to your follow-on question. The issue with the token and logout is a bit extracurricular to the topic of this post, it would be better to post it as a new post/question, with a [mcve].

Comment: No it didn't work for me . Just give me a minute I will give the link

Comment: Here is the link of repo:
https://github.com/MahadiHasan2903/Problem.git.
One more thing I want to mention that. In my navbar I want to conditionally show login and logout.
If user is logged in than show the logout and if not logged in than only show login and not show logout.
That is now working now properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253894/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-mahadi-hasan).